# Algorithm problem with array subsequences

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an algorithm that I have been thinking for a solution, but I couldn't find a way to solve it.

Find all the subsequences of the array consisting of exactly N elements. For example, given array arr = [1,2,3,4], the subsequences consisting of N=3 elements are: `[[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4], [2,3,4]]`.

Comment: Those aren't subsequences, they're subsets.

Comment: @JonasWilms This is subsets, not permutations

Comment: Sorry, that's how I got the problem description. Why was it closed?

Comment: The solutions showed in other algorithms, doe snot have a condition for the size of the ```subsets```

Comment: @barmar true, I always mix up permutations and combinations :)

Comment: @JonasWilms It's not combinations, either. It's subsets.

Comment: @barmar all combinations of a set are also subsets of the set. "More formally, a k-combination of a set S is a subset of k distinct elements of S."

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 The answer I linked to has that, I don't know why it was removed.

Comment: @barmar sorry, I edited in parallel and overwrote your change.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!